# Track logins on SQL Server 7.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-7

We have an old SQL 7 server.  I would like to migrate the databases and users to a new server, but only want to transfer active users.

How can I track logins to determine which users are currently active?

Answer (score 0):

7.0 is a reeeeeally long time ago so my memory may have bad bits in the mix (didn't have checksum back then). Do try to get it upgraded soon as possible. This is so far out of support, MS doesn't even track issues, including new security vulnerabilities on it.

Note that you can always move all logins & users first then start identifying stale/inactive users and removing them. This seems counter intuitive (why bring over garbage then clean up later?) but it's actually the safer path. If you have sleepers that only logs in every end of month or quarter or some random date, you'll likely not capture this user/login accessing the database unless you monitor for a long time.

That said, there's no truly reliable existing source for this information. You can enable the track login success & failure option via SSMS. IIRC, it writes the event to the Windows Log (later versions write to SQL Server event/error log). However, that is only for logins and doesn't actually tell you which database it touches. Easy if it's always a 1-1 mapping between login and user but otherwise, you'll be missing unknown amounts of data.

Safest bet is to create a very lightweight trace just to capture the login, user and database information. Run server-side using sp_trace_xxx rather than profiler so the overhead is lower. Put the tracefile on a separate drive from your mdf and ldf files. We've done this a few times and have never had problems with load so long as the trace is very, very narrowly defined - capture ONLY what is needed, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I will certainly try to run the server-side trace. Brother thanks again. You are great.